# How can I use Realm with Relay/GraphQL

Tags: react-native, realm, graphql, relay

I am working on an react native app where I need some local persistence. Realm looks like a good option. I also have Relay/GraphQL for the app. Relay has its own cache manager, but the cache data has to be fetched from the Realm db. Can someone please let me know if there is a transformation tool that can convert the data fetched from Realm db to Relay appropriate content?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There's no existing transformation tool to my knowledge that integrates Realm with Relay.

Comment: Confirmed - no such tool as far as we know (on the Realm Xamarin team).

Comment: I guess what you want is something like Apollo backed by Realm instead of Redux (I don't know much about Relay and Apollo is targeting web as well).

Answer (score 0):

This project allows you to serve GraphQL from a Realm server: https://github.com/realm/realm-graphql-service